# UIAlertView: alert won't display

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uialertview

Can't get this alert instance to display in this implementation file, and I just can't find the problem.

Everything else works fine.

Any suggestions as to what's wrong?

```
#import "BIDSingleComponentViewController.h"



@implementation BIDSingleComponentViewController

- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    NSInteger row = [self.singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *selected = self.characterNames[row];
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected %@", selected];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:@"Thank you for choosing."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"You're welcome."
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.characterNames = @[@"Luke", @"Leia", @"Han", @"Chewbacca", @"Artoo", @"Threepio", @"Lando"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1; // Incompatible integer to pointer conversion
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.characterNames count];
}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.characterNames[row];
}


@end
```

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDSingleComponentViewController : UIViewController
<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIPickerView *singlePicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *characterNames;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed;

@end
```

Comment: Unrelated to Xcode. Retagged.

Comment: Did you connect the IBAction buttonPressed properly with some action of your button in IB?

Comment: That was the problem. DUH! Thank you. Won't make that mistake again!

Answer (score -2):

In your header file make sure you include the AlertViewDelegate:

```
@interface BIDSingleComponentViewController : UIViewController
<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Also, be sure to connect all outlets to where they belong in IB

Comment: This is incorrect. The delegate is not even used by that alert view.

Comment: doesn't matter in the learning stages of iphone dev. its a good habit to have so you dont miss it later down the line when you want to add to the UIAlertView. And adding it does nothing deconstructive. Me and the answer below were simply trying to figure out what was wrong with the code, because as far as the code reads, everything is set up properly. The problem wasn't even in the code, so anything not deconstructive helps in this case.

Comment: Adding the delegate declaration does not solve the problem. Non deconstructive and correct are two different things, therefore your answer is not correct.